# Get data-price attribute from dynamically added row and put inside the input box

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

how to get data-price inside the text box using select in php html and sql?
i tried this so far. what im trying to do is, when i change the selection box, the input box beside should change base on the value of data-price.

been trying this for a week.

e.g 
select           debit
local treasury   100

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  var chart_add = '<tr id="row_chart'+i+'"><td><select name="chart_of_account[]" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"><option style="width: 400px;">--Select Chart of Account--</option><?php $chart=mysqli_query($conn,"Select acoount_no,account_title from chart_of_account"); while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($chart)){$account_no = $row["acoount_no"]; $account_title = $row["account_title"];?><option value="<?php echo $account_no; ?>" style="width: 400px;"><?php echo $account_no ." | ". $account_title; ?></option><?php }?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="chart_debit[]" class="form-control chart_debit" id="chart_debit"onchange="chart_change_debit()"></td><td><input type="text" name="chart_credit[]" class="form-control chart_credit" id="chart_credit" onchange="chart_change_credit()"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove_chart" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger remove_chart">X</button></td></tr>';
  $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append(chart_add);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
    $('.chart_debit').val($('select[name="chart_of_account"] option:selected').data('price'));
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.remove_chart', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row_chart'+button_id+'').remove();
   
  });
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<form  method = "POST" name="add_name" id="add_name">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- chart of account -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Chart of Account</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Chart of Account</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
                <th rowspan="2"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <input type="text" name="chart_debit_sum" class="form-control chart_debit_sum" id="chart_debit_sum" readonly>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <input type="text" name="chart_credit_sum" class="form-control chart_credit_sum" id="chart_credit_sum" readonly>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <select name="chart_of_account[]" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option style="width: 400px;">--Select Chart of Account--</option>
                    <?php
                    $chart = mysqli_query($conn,"Select acoount_no,account_title from chart_of_account");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chart)){
                      $account_no = $row['acoount_no'];
                      $account_title = $row['account_title'];
                      $amount = $row['test_amount'];
                    ?>
                    <option value = "<?php echo $account_no; ?>" style="width: 400px;" data-price = "<?php echo $amount; ?>">
                      <?php echo $account_no . " | " .$account_title; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chart_debit[]" class="form-control chart_debit" id="chart_debit" onchange="chart_change_debit()">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="chart_credit[]" class="form-control chart_credit" id="chart_credit" onchange="chart_change_credit()">
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- chart of account -->
  </div>
  <!-- chart and sub-->
</div>
</form>
```

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/917cg.png)